# ListView and Buttons

Tags: android, listview, button

I managed to create my ListView which has around 10 items in it but that is nothing more than a list. I am thinking to add some more functionality but I don't know how. I need to add buttons next to each item which is going to be called like " view more" and then some more info will be displayed about the item that was clicked. Anyone has any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to add More button in each ListItem?

Comment: There is no need to add any button for showing detail of that item. You can do it simply by handling onListItemClick(). Check this link - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: If you need to customize your list and define your own UI within it then you can implement a custom adapter class and relate it to your list. there are lots of tutorials out there which can guide you through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before asking a question which in your case is technically a ***request***, visit this page and get familiar with the way people ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/). 
 
 Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

---

I made a simple app for you which has a list with five items and each item has a button named view more. when the user touches that button, the description will pop up in an alert dialog.

**For the layouts we have a main layout which simpley has a listview and nothing more.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_MainItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and since we want our list to be customized, There has to be a layout for our list's item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnViewMore"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnViewMore"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/nullText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewMore"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/ReadMore" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the coding part of classes:

Our Main Activity Class has a function which simpley fills the list with five items I defined:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lstMainItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstMainItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_MainItems);
        fillList();
    }

    // This functions fills the list
    private void fillList() {
        ArrayList<ListProperty> ItemHolder = new ArrayList<ListProperty>();

        ListProperty item0 = new ListProperty();
        ListProperty item1 = new ListProperty();
        ListProperty item2 = new ListProperty();
        ListProperty item3 = new ListProperty();
        ListProperty item4 = new ListProperty();

        item0.setTitle("Item 1");
        item0.setDesc("(1) some description places here...");

        item1.setTitle("Item 2");
        item1.setDesc("(2) some description places here...");

        item2.setTitle("Item 3");
        item2.setDesc("(3) some description places here...");

        item3.setTitle("Item 4");
        item3.setDesc("(4) some description places here...");

        item4.setTitle("Item 5");
        item4.setDesc("(5) some description places here...");

        ItemHolder.add(item0);
        ItemHolder.add(item1);
        ItemHolder.add(item2);
        ItemHolder.add(item3);
        ItemHolder.add(item4);

        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_main, ItemHolder);
        lstMainItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

In order to make our customized list function, we need two essential classes:

1. a Property class which is responsible to set/get Title and Description.
2. an ArrayAdapter class which is aimed to assign User Interface Elements to our Custom Layout File and handle the click event of the button: "View More"

The Property class code:

```
public class ListProperty {

    // Getting and Setting Item Title
    public void setTitle(String itemTitle) {
        this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
    }

    // Getting Item Title
    public String getTitle() {
        return itemTitle;
    }

    // Setting Item Description
    public void setDesc(String itemDesc) {
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
    }

    // Getting Item Description
    public String getDesc() {
        return itemDesc;
    }

    // Defining Variables
    private String itemTitle;
    private String itemDesc;
}
```

The ArrayAdapter Class Code:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListProperty> {

    private static List<ListProperty> Items;
    private Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater l_inflater;

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ListProperty> Items) {
        super(context, R.id.listView_MainItems, textViewResourceId, Items);
        this.context = context;
        this.Items = Items;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        Button btnViewMore;
    }

    public ListProperty getItem(int position) {
        return Items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtItemTitle);
            holder.btnViewMore = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnViewMore);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ListProperty property = (ListProperty) getItem(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(property.getTitle());

        holder.btnViewMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder msgBuilder = new Builder(context);
                msgBuilder.setTitle(property.getTitle());
                msgBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                msgBuilder.setMessage(property.getDesc());
                msgBuilder.setPositiveButton("Return", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertRING = msgBuilder.create();
                alertRING.show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I hope you got what you wanted.

Comment: Hey thanks for your advice and your hard work but I figured out that I could your onlistitemclick listeners and from their position i am just creating new activities. Which way do you thing is better Sir?

Comment: I'm glad I could help.If you know exactly which Items are in your list and there are a specific number of them then onListItemClickListener will do the job but if you like to have more control over your list and you don't know what the list items content could be then you have to make your own ArrayAdapter Class.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, i have 10 specific items in my list and what i am doing now is that whenever an item is clicked i get the position of the item and i am starting a new activity to display some information about that item. Thanks for your help much appriciated.